# Serialize String without escape " to \"

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I want to export a json String for my restful webservice.

My class looks like:

```
public class Animal {
  private String name;
  private JsonElement additionalProperties; //generated with gson
  private String additionalProperties2; //same as above but direct from db
}
```

additionalProperties is a Json field in the db and is returned to Java as String. Idea is, that every animal can have their special properties and anykind of data structure, without the need to model it on Java side.

When I try to export this is use gson.

```
 List<Animal> animals = database.getAllAnimals(); //simplified
 return gson.toJson(animals); // in real via javax.ws.rs.core.Response
```

My problem is that the output looks like:

```
[
  {"name": "Mia", 
   "additionalProperties: "{\"race\": \"dog\"}",
   "additionalProperties2: "{\"race\": \"dog\"}"},
  {...} ...
]
```

Instead I want:

```
[
  {"name": "Mia", 
   "additionalProperties: {"race": "dog"}"
  {...} ...
]
```

I alread tried to build up the JsonObjects without additionalProperties and use "add property" to add additionalProperties. But the output is the same. i guess the problem is the Java String serializen. DB output is correct. additionalProperties is a normal String without encoding of ".

I saw Jacksons property @JsonRawValue. How does this work? Can I make this also with gson?

Comment: How about parsing the JSON properties to a Map<String, Object> (or a Map<String, String> if the JSON is only supposed to contain string properties), and use that as the type of additionalProperties?

Comment: Both of them are not valid JSON.

Comment: additionalProperties could also be a list or contains subelements and sublists.

Comment: Just wondering: why would you ever need it? P.S. Gson does not allow to produce illegal JSON documents.

Comment: Its a special microservice where other service can create events. Some events has additional data and wants to store them. So I created a json field in the db and allow user to add abritoty json objects to the events.

Comment: Well, just change the field type to Object. No need to encode JSON twice.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv How would changing type of `additionalProperties2` to `Object` make any difference, if value assigned to it is still a `String` containing JSON text that was read from the database? Changing the declared type makes no difference.

Comment: @Andreas Ah, yeah, I didn't notice the db mention.

Comment: I feel ashamed for being inattentive. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your [`JsonElement`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) should work fine, so maybe you created it the wrong way.

Second, to output a String value containing JSON text, without escaping it, you can to use a [`@JsonAdapter`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) and [`jsonValue(String value)`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html#jsonValue-java.lang.String-):

> Writes `value` directly to the writer without quoting or escaping.

Example code to show both:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String jsonTextFromDb = "{\"race\": \"dog\"}";

        JsonElement additionalProperties = new JsonParser().parse(jsonTextFromDb);
        Animal animal = new Animal("Mia", additionalProperties, jsonTextFromDb);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(animal));
    }
}

class Animal {
    private String name;
    private JsonElement additionalProperties;
    @JsonAdapter(JsonTextAdapter.class)
    private String additionalProperties2;
    Animal(String name, JsonElement additionalProperties, String additionalProperties2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
        this.additionalProperties2 = additionalProperties2;
    }
}

class JsonTextAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String str) throws IOException {
        out.jsonValue(str);
    }
    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return new JsonParser().parse(in).toString();
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
{
  "name": "Mia",
  "additionalProperties": {
    "race": "dog"
  },
  "additionalProperties2": {"race": "dog"}
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks